# find closest time value of each pandas group

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2014-06-22 17:46:00', '2014-06-24 16:52:00', '2014-06-25 20:02:00', '2014-06-25 17:55:00', '2014-07-02 11:36:00', '2014-07-06 12:40:00', '2014-07-05 12:46:00', '2014-07-27 15:12:00'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']})

>>> df
                  date type
0  2014-06-22 17:46:00    A
1  2014-06-24 16:52:00    A
2  2014-06-25 20:02:00    A
3  2014-06-25 17:55:00    B
4  2014-07-02 11:36:00    B
5  2014-07-06 12:40:00    C
6  2014-07-05 12:46:00    C
7  2014-07-27 15:12:00    C
```

How can I get the indices of each group's element with the closest time to, say, 17:00 hrs (disregarding the day)? The desired outcome would be:

```
>>> df.groupby('type').date. ???
type
A    1
B    3
C    7
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Also, what if I wanted to find the closest but earlier than a given time? With 17:00 hrs again it would need to return:

```
>>> df.groupby('type').date. ???
type
A    1
B    4
C    7
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get default dates, add `time`s and get difference with time `t`:

First get minimal indices of absolute values per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html), for second solution get maximal negative values per groups by replacing positive values by `NaN`s by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2014-06-22 17:46:00', '2014-06-22 16:52:00', 
                            '2014-06-25 20:02:00', '2014-06-25 17:55:00', 
                            '2014-07-02 11:36:00', '2014-07-06 12:40:00', 
                            '2014-07-05 12:46:00', '2014-07-27 15:12:00'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']})
```

---

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

t = '17:00:00'
a = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) - pd.to_datetime(t)
print (a)
0            00:46:00
1   -1 days +23:52:00
2            03:02:00
3            00:55:00
4   -1 days +18:36:00
5   -1 days +19:40:00
6   -1 days +19:46:00
7   -1 days +22:12:00
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]


b = a.abs().groupby(df['type']).idxmin()
print (b)
type
A    1
B    3
C    7
Name: date, dtype: int64

c = a.mask(a > pd.Timedelta(0)).groupby(df['type']).idxmax()
print (c)
type
A    1
B    4
C    7
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

**Detail**:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, a, a.abs(), a.mask(a >  pd.Timedelta(0))], axis=1)
df1.columns = ['date','type','diff','absolute diff','max negative']
print (df1)
                 date type              diff absolute diff      max negative
0 2014-06-22 17:46:00    A          00:46:00      00:46:00               NaT
1 2014-06-22 16:52:00    A -1 days +23:52:00      00:08:00 -1 days +23:52:00
2 2014-06-25 20:02:00    A          03:02:00      03:02:00               NaT
3 2014-06-25 17:55:00    B          00:55:00      00:55:00               NaT
4 2014-07-02 11:36:00    B -1 days +18:36:00      05:24:00 -1 days +18:36:00
5 2014-07-06 12:40:00    C -1 days +19:40:00      04:20:00 -1 days +19:40:00
6 2014-07-05 12:46:00    C -1 days +19:46:00      04:14:00 -1 days +19:46:00
7 2014-07-27 15:12:00    C -1 days +22:12:00      01:48:00 -1 days +22:12:00
```

Comment: I'm undoing acceptance of this answer because I think there is a problem with it (please correct me if I'm wrong) in regards to q1: For the sake of the argument, change the times of group `A` in the original `df` to, say, `17:46:00`, `16:52:00` and `20:02:00`. In that case, the closest time is `16:52:00` but this method will return `17:46:00` since after converting to `int` it understands differences in base ten system.

Comment: You are right, so solution was modified for timedeltas. also for `A` group was changed values by comment, so a bit different output. Can you check it?

Comment: It is not working because `df['date']` is still a `str` so calling `.dt..` returns an error. I am not sure how you prefer to do it so I will not edit your answer but let you correct it if you feel like it. Based on your answers I also worked out a similar one which is working so posting below. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I forget it, so now it was added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is on way by using `idxmin`

```
df['New']=abs(pd.to_datetime('2018-02-08'+' '+df['date'].dt.time.astype(str))-pd.to_datetime('2018-02-08 17:00'))


df.groupby('type').New.idxmin()
Out[123]: 
type
A    2
B    3
C    7
Name: New, dtype: int64
```

For forward search

```
df['New']=(pd.to_datetime('2018-02-08'+' '+df['date'].dt.time.astype(str))-pd.to_datetime('2018-02-08 17:00'))
df['New']=df['New'].where(df['New'].dt.total_seconds()<0).abs()
df.groupby('type').New.idxmin()
Out[134]: 
type
A    0
B    4
C    7
Name: New, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you state the python and pandas version you run it with? In 3.5, 0.19.2, `df['date'].dt.time.astype(str)` returns `TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index`. Because that's also a brilliant solution, it might be helpful for future users to have this working as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logic of @Wen's and @jezrael's solutions, and while waiting for their edits to overcome some minor issues, I worked out another one that is functional:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2014-06-22 17:46:00', '2014-06-24 16:52:00', '2014-06-25 20:02:00', '2014-06-25 17:55:00', '2014-07-02 11:36:00', '2014-07-06 12:40:00', '2014-07-05 12:46:00', '2014-07-27 15:12:00'],
    'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']})

print(df)
                  date type
0  2014-06-22 17:46:00    A
1  2014-06-24 16:52:00    A
2  2014-06-25 20:02:00    A
3  2014-06-25 17:55:00    B
4  2014-07-02 11:36:00    B
5  2014-07-06 12:40:00    C
6  2014-07-05 12:46:00    C
7  2014-07-27 15:12:00    C
```

question 1:

```
#convert str to datetime type
df['dateDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
#create col with specific time, and each lines date
df['5pm'] = pd.to_datetime(df.dateDT.dt.date.astype(str) + ' 17:00:00')
#find time difference in seconds
df['tDiff5pm'] = abs((df.dateDT - df['5pm']).dt.total_seconds())
#get min diff per group 
print(df.tDiff5pm.abs().groupby(df['type']).idxmin())
type
A    1
B    3
C    7
Name: tDiff5pm, dtype: int64
```

question 2:

```
#as above but no absolute values
df['tDiff5pm2'] = (df.dateDT - df['5pm']).dt.total_seconds()
#NaNs to later times, then abs (got this from @Wen's answer
df['onlyEarlier']=df['tDiff5pm2'].where(df['tDiff5pm2']<0).abs()
#get min diff per group 
print(df.groupby('type').onlyEarlier.idxmin())
type
A    1
B    4
C    7
Name: onlyEarlier, dtype: int64
```